# Name variables convention with underscore or not

Tags: magento2, coding-standards

I find that some protected variables in the Magento core come with an underscore prefix and some don't.

Also some parameters in di.xml do not have an underscore

```
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product">
<arguments>        
    .....
    <argument name="productRepository" xsi:type="object">Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface\Proxy</argument>
</arguments>
</type>
```

This protected var `$productRepository` does not have an underscore. Is there any reason for this ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Magento 2 follows the [PSR-2](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-2-coding-style-guide.md) coding standard, which states:

#### 4.2

> Property names SHOULD NOT be prefixed with a single underscore to indicate protected or private visibility.

#### 4.3

> Method names SHOULD NOT be prefixed with a single underscore to indicate protected or private visibility.

The only reason that you will find protected properties (or methods) **with** leading underscores is if it is code ported from Magento 1 and not refactored yet. Magento 1 followed the [Zend Coding Standard](https://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/coding-standard.naming-conventions.html) of Zend Framework 1:

> For methods on objects that are declared with the "private" or "protected" modifier, the first character of the method name must be an underscore. This is the only acceptable application of an underscore in a method name. Methods declared "public" should never contain an underscore.

Comment: in future i should use variable not have underscore. Old code contain underscore will be remove soon right?

Comment: Yes, that is how it should be

Comment: Strongly agreed with @FabianSchmengler, but recently I have noticed a very weird issue with MEQP2 (https://github.com/magento/magento-coding-standard). When I set up this and connected with PhpStorm, the phpcs gave me warning that Private variables must be prefixed with an underscore. Magento clearly indicated at https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/coding-standards/code-standard-php.html we must use MEQP2. Why this difference then? Need you views on this.